# Scapy не сканирует телефоны

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

```
import scapy.all as scapy

class scan:
    def Arp(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        print(ip)
        arp_r = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
        br = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
        request = br/arp_r
        answered, unanswered = scapy.srp(request, timeout=1)
        print('\tIP\t\t\t\t\tMAC')
        print('_' * 37)
        for i in answered:
            ip, mac = i[1].psrc, i[1].hwsrc
            print(ip, '\t\t' + mac)
            print('-' * 37)

arp = scan() # создаем экземпляр класса
arp.Arp('192.168.0.1/24') # вызываем метод
```

Этот код представляет собой arp сканер, он сканирует все хосты в сети **кроме телефонов**, почему так получается?

Answer (score 0):

Я только лишь предположу, что телефоны находятся, в отличии от других устройств, которые подключены к сети не по Wi-Fi, в сети не постоянно, а лишь время от времени активируют подключение. Потому, в результатах сканирования телефоны могут быть и не видны. я попробовал сканировать сеть с телефоном. Его видно в сети через раз. То есть в результатах, то нет.

Но, это лишь только предположение.